# Is there any way to use knockout's "if" binding to load elements to the page but not evaluate other bindings?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm in a situation where I need to load elements to the DOM that have knockout bindings, but I don't always want these bindings to evaluate.  In the following example, see the inner div for what I mean:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: planets">
    <li>
        Planet: <b data-bind="text: name"> </b>
        <div data-bind="if: capital">
            I still want to load this text for later display, when I define "capital"
            Capital: <b data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
    ko.applyBindings({
        planets: [
            { name: 'Mercury', capital: null }, 
            { name: 'Earth', capital: { cityName: 'Barnsley' } }        
        ]
    });
</script>
```

My particular scenario is that I have "editing" and "not editing" templates for an element I'm loading into the dom, both of which are loaded to the page.  When I add a new instance of this element to the page, I run into issues because the "not editing" template is loaded and looks for values that have yet to be defined (because the user is adding them to a new object).

My particular example:

```
<!-- ko foreach: books -->
    <div data-bind="visible: !editing()" class="row-fluid card-box">
        <div data-bind="visible: !isPaperback()"> // I want to load this but not evaluate the isPaperback because the user hasn't defined that yet - currently getting null reference errors here  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: editing" class="row-fluid card-box">

    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

One solution I can think of is paired with my question above, but if there's a better way to make this work, I'm definitely open to suggestions.  Would it be better to just have non-null default values for my "newBook" object, which gets pushed into the 'books' array when the user clicks "Add"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make your `capital` property observable and use the `if` binding to restrict the area. Then, when you do populate `capital`, the binding will react and display your content.

Here is a sample:

```
var Planet = function(data) {
   this.name = data.name;
   this.capital = ko.observable(data.capital);
};

var viewModel = {
    planets: [
        new Planet({ name: 'Mercury', capital: null }),
        new Planet({ name: 'Earth', capital: { cityName: 'Barnsley' } })
    ]
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

//populate capital in 2 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.planets[0].capital({ cityName: "Gotham" });
}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QqPfV/

Comment: Thanks Ryan!  If you have a moment - Can you give me an example of when visible would be better to use than if?  It seems like they do the same thing except if only loads what's needed.

Comment: `visible` toggles `display: none` on the element, so the children are still rendered and bound, just not displayed.  Two situations that are good for `if`: 1- when bindings would fail, if the child elements were bound (nested properties are null/undefined).  2- when binding the child elements is expensive and not normally accessed.